# How do I access a particular element in a Force.com SOAP response?

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, salesforce

I am having difficulty accessing a particular element nested in my SOAP object result. The Salesforce toolkit is returning the following when I run this code:

`print_r ($response->records[0]->fields`

RETURNS

> stdClass Object (
>
> [Number_of_Residents_*c] => 1 
>   
> [State*_c] => LA 
>  [City__c] => New Orleans 
>   
> [Placement_Incentive__c] => Yes  
> [Total_number_of_schools__c] =>
>   125.0  
> [Total_Number_of_Students__c] => 24471.0  
> [Total_Number_of_Employees__c] =>
>   1700.0  
> [Total_Operating_Revenue__c] => 1.2E8  
> [Governance_Model__c] => Mayoral/State Control 
>   
> [CEO_Superintendent_Appointment_Year__c]
>   => 2007  
> [Trained_Leader__c] =>  
> [Final_Press_Clip_1_Title__c] => Clip
>   1 Sample  
> [Final_Approved_Clip_1__c]
>   => http://www.google.com  
> [Final_Press_Clip_2_Title__c] => Clip
>   2 Sample  
> [Final_Approved_Clip_2__c]
>   => http://www.yahoo.com  
> [Final_Press_Clip_3_Title__c] => Clip
>   3 Sample  
> [Final_Approved_Clip_3__c]
>   => http://www.bing.com  
> [Final_Press_Clip_4_Title__c] => 
>   
> [Final_Approved_Clip_4__c] => 
>   
> [Final_Press_Clip_5_Title__c] => 
>   
> [Final_Approved_Clip_5__c] => 
>   
> [News_Clip_Status__c] => Complete 
>   
> [New_Organization__c] => Yes 
>   
> [Student_Achievment_URL__c] =>
>   http://www.aol.com  
> [Work_Life__c] => 
>   
> [Placement_Incentive_Description__c]
>   => $1000  
> [0] => SObject Object (    [type] => Account    [fields] =>
>   stdClass Object ([Name] => Sample District Name) ) 
>  [2] => SObject
>   Object (    [type] => Contact
>   [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Name]
>   => Paul Smith ) ) )

If I want to get the value of Placement_Incentive_Description__c I can do so by using:

> print_r
>   ($response->records[0]->fields->Placement_Incentive_Description__c

However the difficult lies in how to access the name field in the Account object which seems to be a child of a field named [0]. I have tried several combinations but have had no luck.

Comment: Man, it's really unreadable, could you format it better?

Comment: I added some line breaks to make it a bit more pleasant to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow thats weird try something like this.

$attr = 0;

$response->records[0]->fields->{$attr}

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, and also thanks for validating the fact that is strange output. I suspect the toolkit that is producing the object is probably not outputting appropriately.